# How to handle Exception when Zend_Acl is On? it gives Resource 'default::error::error' not found'

Tags: php, zend-framework, exception, zend-acl

i've implemeted the Zend_Acl and its seems to be working.my resources are links :

> module_name . "::" . controller_name . "::" . action_name;

i've added something in my code that's breaking and it seems that's i'm redirected to the usual error page but that the Acl comes in saying

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Acl_Exception' with message 'Resource 'default::error::error' not found' in F:\work\php\zendworkspace\myproject\library\Zend\Acl.php on line 365

i have added the `default::error::error` to the resources but the error is still the same.
when i remove the code that's breaking the whole thing works again.
So i would definitely have the same error when something breaks in my code.

I would like to find out how to solve this. thanks for reading and  sharing your experience.

**Edit:**

the code to implement that is kind of long. this is a db driven ACL with doctrine.
i've modified [this tutorial](http://blog.davidjclarke.co.uk/database-driven-zend-acl-tutorial-part-two.html) to implement mine.i've cut out the myACL class, looks the same as the one in the tutorial, and the ACL plugin is kind of the same.i've registerd it in the application.ini.

```
// this class build all the roles and resouces and add 2 users to 2 differents roles and so on
class CMS_Util_AddResourcesAndRoles {

private $arrModules = array();
private $arrControllers = array();
public $arrActions = array();
private $arrIgnores = array('.', '..', '.svn');

public function BuildMCAArrays() {
    $this->BuildModuleArray();
    $this->BuildControllersArray();
    $this->BuildActionArray();
    return $this;
}

public function CheckData() {
    if (count($this->arrModules) < 1)
        throw new CMS_Exception_ResourceNotFound("No Modules found ..");

    if (count($this->arrControllers) < 1)
        throw new CMS_Exception_ResourceNotFound("No Controllers found ..");

    if (count($this->arrActions) < 1)
        throw new CMS_Exception_ResourceNotFound("No Actions found ..");
}

public function BuildModuleArray() {
    $cmsApplicationModules = opendir(APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'modules');
    while (false !== ($cmsFile = readdir($cmsApplicationModules))) {
        if (!in_array($cmsFile, $this->arrIgnores)) {
            if (is_dir(APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'modules' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $cmsFile)) {
                $this->arrModules[] = $cmsFile;
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($cmsApplicationModules);
    return $this->arrModules;
}

public function BuildControllersArray() {
    if (count($this->arrModules) > 0) {
        foreach ($this->arrModules as $strModuleName) {
            $cmsControllerFolder = opendir(APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "modules" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $strModuleName . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "controllers");
            while (false !== ($cmsFile = readdir($cmsControllerFolder))) {
                if (!in_array($cmsFile, $this->arrIgnores)) {
                    if (preg_match('/Controller/', $cmsFile)) {
 //     if(strtolower(substr($cmsFile, 0, -14)) != "error")
 //     $this->arrControllers[$strModuleName][] = strtolower(substr($cmsFile, 0, -14));
                        $this->arrControllers[$strModuleName][] = strtolower (substr($cmsFile, 0, -14));
                    }
                }
            }
            closedir($cmsControllerFolder);
        }
    }
    return $this->arrControllers;
}

private function BuildActionArray() {
//        $arrMethods = array();
    if (count($this->arrControllers) > 0) {
        foreach ($this->arrControllers as $strModule => $strController) {
            foreach ($strController as $strController) {
                if ($strModule == "default") {
                    $strClassName = ucfirst($strController . 'Controller');
                } else {
                    $strClassName = ucfirst($strModule) . '_' . ucfirst($strController . 'Controller');
                }

                if (!class_exists($strClassName)) {
                    Zend_Loader::loadFile(APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'modules' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $strModule . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'controllers' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ucfirst($strController) . 'Controller.php');
                }

                $objReflection = new Zend_Reflection_Class($strClassName);
                $arrMethods = $objReflection->getMethods();
                foreach ($arrMethods as $arrMethod) {
                    if (preg_match('/Action/', $arrMethod->name)) {
                        $this->arrActions[$strModule][$strController][] = substr($arrMethod->name, 0, -6);
  //  $this->arrActions[$strModule][$strController][] = substr($this->_camelCaseToHyphens($objMethods->name), 0, -6);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->arrActions;
}

private function _camelCaseToHyphens($string) {
    if ($string == 'currentPermissionsAction') {
        $found = true;
    }
    $length = strlen($string);
    $convertedString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        if (ord($string[$i]) > ord('A') && ord($string[$i]) < ord('Z')) {
            $convertedString .= '-' . strtolower($string[$i]);
        } else {
            $convertedString .= $string[$i];
        }
    }
    return strtolower($convertedString);
}

public function WriteResourcesToDb() {
    $this->BuildMCAArrays();
    $this->CheckData();
    $resources = array();

    foreach ($this->arrModules as $strModuleName) {
        if (array_key_exists($strModuleName, $this->arrControllers)) {
            foreach ($this->arrControllers[$strModuleName] as $strControllerName) {
                if (array_key_exists($strControllerName, $this->arrActions[$strModuleName])) {
                    foreach ($this->arrActions[$strModuleName][$strControllerName] as $strActionName) {
                        $res = new CMS_Model_Resource();
                        $res->module_name = $strModuleName;
                        $res->controller_name = $strControllerName;
                        $res->action_name = $strActionName;
                        $res->name = $strModuleName . "_" . $strControllerName . "_" . $strActionName;
                        $resources[] = $res;

                        $this->PersistResource($resources);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

private function PersistResource(array $resourceobject) {
    try {
        $collection = new Doctrine_Collection("CMS_Model_Resource");
        foreach ($resourceobject as $resource) {
            $collection->add($resource);
        }
        $collection->save();
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
    }
}


public function WriteRoleAndUserstoDb(){
    $guest = new CMS_Model_Role();
    $guest->name = "guest";
    $guest->description = "simple user";
    $guest->canbedeleted = true;

    $member = new CMS_Model_Role();
    $member->name = "member";
    $member->description = "member with limited privileges,can access member reserved resources";
    $member->canbedeleted = true;

    $publisher = new CMS_Model_Role();
    $publisher->name = "publisher";
    $publisher->description = "publisher with publish an unpublished privileges";
    $publisher->canbedeleted = true;

    $manager = new CMS_Model_Role();
    $manager->name = "manager";
    $manager->description = "manager with privileges to publish, to unpublish, general manager of the site";
    $manager->canbedeleted = true;

    $admin = new CMS_Model_Role();
    $admin->name = "administrator";
    $admin->description = "admin with all privileges";
    $admin->canbedeleted = false;

    $superadmin = new CMS_Model_Role();
    $superadmin->name = "superadmin";
    $superadmin->description = "superadmin to rule them all";
    $superadmin->canbedeleted = false;


    $superadmin->Parents[0] = $admin;
    $admin->Parents[0] = $manager;
    $manager->Parents[0] = $publisher;
    $publisher->Parents[0] = $member;
    $member->Parents[0] = $guest;


    $adminname = new CMS_Model_User();
    $adminname->id = CMS_Util_Common::uuid();
    $adminname->first_name = "adminname";
    $adminname->last_name = "surname";
    $adminname->full_name = "adminname surname";
    $adminname->password = "password";
    $adminname->email = "mister@somemail.com";
    $adminname->is_active = true;
    $adminname->is_verified = true;
    $adminname->username ="superadmin";
    $adminname->Role = $superadmin;

    $adminname2 = new CMS_Model_User();
    $adminname2->id = CMS_Util_Common::uuid();
    $adminname2->first_name = "adminname2";
    $adminname2->last_name = "adminsurname";
    $adminname2->email="shallom@someemail.fr";
    $adminname2->full_name = "adminname2 adminsurname";
    $adminname2->password = "adminadmin";
    $adminname2->is_active = true;
    $adminname2->is_verified = true;
    $adminname2->username ="admin";
    $adminname2->Role = $admin;

    $thepublisher = new CMS_Model_User();
    $thepublisher->id = CMS_Util_Common::uuid();
    $thepublisher->first_name = "one publisher";
    $thepublisher->last_name = "lastname";
    $thepublisher->full_name = "something something";
    $thepublisher->email = "user@somegmail.com";
    $thepublisher->password = "password";
    $thepublisher->username = "publisher";
    $thepublisher->is_active = true;
    $thepublisher->is_verified = true;
    $thepublisher->Role = $publisher;



    $conn = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();
    $conn->flush();
    return $this;
}


public function AssignResourcesToRoles(){

    $guestcollection = new Doctrine_Collection("CMS_Model_RoleResource");
    $guestroles = Doctrine_Core::getTable("CMS_Model_Role")->GetRoleByName("guest");
    $defautresources = Doctrine_Core::getTable("CMS_Model_Resource")->GetResourceByModule("default");
    foreach($defautresources as $resource){
        $guestroleresource = new CMS_Model_RoleResource();
        $guestroleresource->Role = $guestroles;
        $guestroleresource->Resource = $resource;
        $guestcollection->add($guestroleresource);
    }

    $guestcollection->save();

    $admincollection = new Doctrine_Collection("CMS_Model_RoleResource");
    $adminroles = Doctrine_Core::getTable("CMS_Model_Role")->GetRoleByName("superadmin");
    $adminresources = Doctrine_Core::getTable("CMS_Model_Resource")->GetResourceByModule("admin");


    foreach($adminresources as $resource){
        $adminroleresource = new CMS_Model_RoleResource();
        $adminroleresource->Role = $adminroles;
        $adminroleresource->Resource = $resource;
        $admincollection->add($adminroleresource);
    }

    $admincollection->save();
    return $this;
}


public function SetAclUp(){
    $this->WriteResourcesToDb();
    $this->WriteRoleAndUserstoDb();
    $this->AssignResourcesToRoles();
    return $this;
 }
}
```

as you can see i've granted all links under default to role `guest` meaning `guest` can see the `default::error::error page` when there is a problem.

I can also assure you that, when nothing is broken in my code, i can login with the `publisher` credential and get bounced anytime i'm trying to go to the admin panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most popular error is that you have not added the resource for any instance.

Comment: hello gtOkAi i've edited the post to show that users/instances have been granted resources including the `guest`.they are all loaded from the database.

if in anycase i don't understand what you meant by `not added the resource for any instance.` then please elaborate more on it. thanks for responding